# Unable to store the data from node.js to mongoDB atlas below are the code snippets

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm Unable to store the data from node.js to mongoDB atlas below are the code snippets.

Below is the app.js code where i established the mongodb connection.

```
const express = require("express");
var app = express();
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const Post=require("./models/post");
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(cors());
app.post('/sms', function (req, res) {
  let obj=JSON.parse(req.body.user);
   const user= new Post({
     userName:obj.userName,
     password:obj.password,
     email:obj.email,
     address:obj.address
   })
  user.save()
  .then(data => {
    res.json(data),
    res.status(200).json({data})
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.json(err)
  });
})
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://srihari:srihari@cluster0-yuykq.mongodb.net/srihari?retryWrites=true&w=majority",{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true},()=>{
  console.log("DB connected!");
})
app.listen(8080);
```

Below is the code of Schema to bind the data which is coming from frontend.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const postschema=mongoose.Schema({
    userName:{
        type:String 
    },
    password:{
        type:String
    },
    email:{
        type:String 
    },  
    address:{
        type:String 
    },

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts',postschema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Async/Await functions when storing/retrieving data in mongodb;

```
   const express = require("express");
   var app = express();
   const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
   const cors = require("cors");
   const Post=require("./models/post");
   const mongoose=require("mongoose");
   app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
   app.use(bodyparser.json())
   app.use(cors());
   app.post('/sms', async function (req, res) {
     let obj=JSON.parse(req.body.user);
      const user= new Post({
         userName:obj.userName,
         password:obj.password,
         email:obj.email,
         address:obj.address
      })
      await user.save()
      .then(data => {
         res.json(data),
         res.status(200).json({data})
       })
       .catch(err => {
          res.json(err)
       });
    })
     mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://srihari:srihari@cluster0-yuykq.mongodb.net/srihari?retryWrites=true&w=majority",{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true},()=>{
     console.log("DB connected!");
      })
     app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: This line of code **let obj=JSON.parse(req.body.user);** should be this instead **let obj=JSON.stringify(req.body.user);**

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using Schema directly. First you have to define it like below.

const Schema = mongoose.Schema ;

Write above line of code after you imported the mongoose.